# querySelector() combine multiple attribute selectors

Tags: javascript, selectors-api

I have a input field with class of this format:

```
some_starting_constant_string somevariablestring some_ending_constant_string
```

So I want a querySelector that uses a combination of starts with and ends with:

```
document.querySelectorAll("input[class^='some_starting_constant_string' AND class$='some_ending_constant_string']
```

Is this possible? Combining a starts with and ends with rule?

Comment: Is it that you want to collect all objects with both classes, or that you want the results of both queries to be in one returned value?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just have to separate both attribute selectors :

`input[class^='some_starting_constant_string'][class$='some_ending_constant_string']`

```js
console.log(
  document.querySelectorAll("[class^='start'][class$='end']")
)
```

```html
<div class="start__end"></div>
<div class="start_heretoo_end"></div>
<div class="sta__end"></div>
<div class="rt__end"></div>
<div class="start__d"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to do it so element return are in a specific order

```
querySelectorOrdered =(...selectors)=> {

    let arrOut = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < selectors.length; i++)
    {
      arrOut.push(...document.querySelectorAll(selectors[i]));
    }

   return arrOut;
 }
```

reference: vb6code.com/code-javascript-queryselectorall-ordered.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="start__end"></div>
<div class="start_heretoo_end"></div>
<div class="sta__end"></div>
<div class="rt__end"></div>
<div class="start__d"></div>
```

To select elements that have class attributes containing specific patterns, you can use the attribute selectors in querySelectorAll() method. Here's how you can select elements that have classes containing both "start" and "end":

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('[class*="start"][class*="end"]');
```